# How to dump a particular column from a row of a text file in pig ?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to pig.I have my data in .txt file and i want to retrieve a particular column from this text file.The columns are separated with `;` in this text file.

For example, if the row is

`1;1;13;2010-09-13T19:16:26.763;239;383084;10;16575;2013-04-05T15:50:48.133;2015-11-21T04:55:50.150;I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?;2;0;162;2011-01-25T08:44:10.820;` ,

then i want to retrieve the **4th** column from the above row.

So,what should be the pig script to retrieve the **4th** column i.e  `(239)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have semi-colon as delimiter  use PigStorage

```
A = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING PigStorage(';');
dump A
```

Output of dump A:

> (1,1,13,2010-09-13T19:16:26.763,239,383084,10,16575,2013-04-05T15:50:48.133,2015-11-21T04:55:50.150,I've
>   rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from
>   rooting?,2,0,162,2011-01-25T08:44:10.820)

```
B =foreach A generate $4;
dump B
```

Output of dump B

> (239)

You can use AS in load command if u want to give names to your column and retrive with that name

```
 A = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING PigStorage(';') AS(col1,col2...);

 Dumping given column with name. 
 B =foreach A generate col1;
 dump B
```